# Парсинг xml с помощью DOM

Tags: парсер

```js
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class ReadXMLtests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("http://ria.ru/export/rss2/tourism/index.xml");

            NodeList nl1;
            nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
            System.out.println(nl1.getLength());

            for ( int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++){
                Element item = (Element)nl1.item(i);
                System.out.println(item.getTextContent());
            }

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь средствами android studio создать новостную ленту. Остановился на следующем моменте: Дом-парсер читает нужный xml, сообщает, что нашел N результатов, и выводит текст, но КАК и КУДА эти результаты правильно передать, чтобы они попали непосредственно на экран приложения?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все просто, для этого нужно написать адаптер. По ссылке хороший пример XML парсера:
http://m.habrahabr.ru/company/surfingbird/blog/248647/

Comment: Адаптер написан. Я так понимаю рез-т парсинга представлен в NodeList, но как с ним работать, смутно представляю. Или его нужно в ArrayList как-то конвертировать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.